# How to fine tune an asp.net application and find bottlenecks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, visual-studio-2010

How can I test performance of an asp.net mvc application and understand where exactly the bottlenecks are? I see some tools from redgate but to get the package is about $700. Are there any cheaper alternatives that may work? Or simple ways to really fine tune the application to maximize performance in a less expensive manner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. There is one stackoverflow created called MiniProfiler.

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek9ASPNETMiniProfilerFromStackExchangeRocksYourWorld.aspx

Comment: Apart from watching what is going on on the server side, you also need to see what is going on on the client side. Google Page Speed, YSlow, firebug and some other tools may also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS 2010 Ultimate you have access to some decent performance testing tools that are included.  Many time bottlenecks only show themselves when the application is under load.  The tools in VS let you correlate the load test with performance counters on the server hosting the app.  This in combination with the MiniProfiler tool mentioned in another answer would be a good combo for finding bottlenecks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540.aspx